# How to accept a django.http.HttpResponse object containing a csv file in Ajax?

Tags: django, ajax

When I click a button on the html page, I want to **trigger a query in backend database, creating a csv file specific to the request and then download it**.

I managed to pass data to `django`, however, I **cannot** find a way to trigger download as I click the button and I don't know how to make `ajax` accept `django.http.HttpResponse` containing csv.

Meanwhile I find everything is ok if I visit the url directly, but when I use `ajax` it's not the case.

For illustration,

My `urls.py` is:

```py
url('export/',views.export)
```

My `views.py` is:

```py
def export(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':

        export_list = json.loads(request.GET['id_list'])

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'
        
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow(['column_1','column_2'])

        for id in export_list:
            item = Item.objects.get(id=id)
            witer.writerow([item.attr_1,item.attr_2])

        return response
```

And my `html` is

```js
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="export" rel="external nofollow" role="button" style="margin-left: 30px;">export to csv</a>

$("#export").click( function(){
    data.id_list = JSON.stringify(paperids);
    data.csrfmiddlewaretoken = '{{ csrf_token }}';
    $.ajax({
            url: '/export/',
            type: 'GET',
            data: data,
            dataType: "text/csv",
            headers:{ 'Accept': 'text/csv','Content-Type': 'text/csv' };
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: fucntion(){
                console.log("why");
            }
    })
```

**How can I manage to download the csv when clicking the button?**

Answer (score 0):

I find `Ajax` **cannot** handle download request. I now post data through the `hidden input` in a `form` and return a download response instead.